# find the particular integral?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

find the  complete   integral   of the  PDE  $$\frac{ \partial^2u }{\partial x^2} +  2 \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x \partial y} + \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2} = xe^{x+y}$$

My attempt :  auxiliary equation  is  $m^2 +2m +1  =0$ ,that is $m = -1,-1$

so the  complementary  function will  be   $f_1 (y+x)  + xf_2(y+x)$

Now  the particular integral  , $$P.I  = \frac{xe^{x+y}}{(D+1)^2}$$

after that im not able to proceed further

Also  i know that  complete  integral = C.F + P.I

any hints/solution will bne appreciated

thanks u

Comment: You can use the $\text{\partial}\ \partial$ symbol.

Comment: @YvesDaoust  okss

Comment: Why this downvote ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust I guess sometimes they come from aesthetical considerations, in the same sense you like or not rock music.

Comment: @RafaBudría: interesting point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $(\partial_x^2+2\partial_x\partial_y+\partial_y^2) (x^n e^{x+y})=(2x^n+4nx^{n-1}+n(n-1)x^{n-2})e^{x+y}$, with special cases $(\partial_x^2+2\partial_x\partial_y+\partial_y^2)e^{x+y}=2e^{x+y}$ and $(\partial_x^2+2\partial_x\partial_y+\partial_y^2)(x e^{x+y})=(2x+4)e^{x+y}$, the particular integral is $(\frac{x}{2}-1)e^{x+y}$. (You'll want to double-check all my arithmetic.)

Comment: Complete integral is
$u=f_1 (y-x)  + xf_2(y-x)+\frac{( x-1) e^{y+x}}{4}$